# Консультация по API Яндекс карт, зоны доставки

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Дано: [Яндекс карта](https://yandex.ru/maps/?um=constructor%3Aeba3b27a465f68ea5f51155a9fd6673f7ea6fcf411a68481fb68a388f716568d&source=constructorLink) карта собранная через конструктор путём наложения двух многоугольников друг на друга. В данном случае зелёный наложен на синий. 
Если делать без наложения то синий многоугольник который окружает в данном случае зелёный многоугольник будет иметь некрасивый шов [скрин](http://take.ms/muDKq).

Задача осложняется тем, что нужно создать 5 полигонов соответствующих условиям доставки:

По Москве в пределах МКАД - Бесплатно
По Москве, за МКАД и по Московской области
до 10 км - 399 Р
до 20 км - 499 Р
до 30 км - 599 Р
до 50 км - 799 Р

Как Вы уже поняли, надо чтобы полигон соответствовал километражу от МКАД.

Вопрос первый: Как избавиться от шва в полигонах, если делать без наложения?
Вопрос второй: как сделать чтобы полигон имел ограничение по расстоянию от МКАД?

Так понимаю в рамках конструктора это не решить, или возможно?

Comment: "Как избавиться от шва в полигонах, если делать без наложения?" У многоугольников могут быть внутренние контуры которые вырезают в нём дырку. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon

Comment: В рамках конструктора это решается путём натыкивания точек по нужным вам координатам. Для того чтобы узнать расстояние есть линейка или длина линии. Но конечно там нет функции "создать полигон каждая точка которого лежит на расстоянии 10 км от мкад".  Второй вариант: найти где-то координаты МКАД и сгенерировать многоугольник с нужными вам координатами. Каждая координата которого лежит на расстоянии 10км от МКАД. Но имхо, первый вариант проще)

Comment: в приципе я так и думал